# Getting the exception "The type 'Expander' was not found"

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-toolkit, expander

I have something like this in my Silverlight application:

```
<navigation:Page x:Class="PPCa.Modules.ProjectManager.Client.Views.ProjectDetailView" 
                 xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
                 xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" 
                 xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
                 xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
                 xmlns:sdk="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation/sdk" 
                 xmlns:data="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls;assembly=System.Windows.Controls.Data.DataForm.Toolkit" 
                 xmlns:navigation="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls;assembly=System.Windows.Controls.Navigation"
                 xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:PPCa.Common.Infrastructure.Controls;assembly=PPCa.Common.Infrastructure"
                 xmlns:toolkit="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation/toolkit" 
                 mc:Ignorable="d"
                 d:DesignHeight="768"
                 d:DesignWidth="1024"
                 Title="ProjectDetailView Page">
    <toolkit:Expander>
    </toolkit:Expander>
</navigation:Page>
```

It compiles fine, but I get the exception "The type 'Expander' was not found."  When I run the application and navigate to the page.

**Edits:**

I've tried changing the toolkit namespace to:

```
xmlns:toolkit="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls;assembly=System.Windows.Controls.Toolkit"
```

and now it still compiles and I get the exception:

> The type 'Expander' was not found
>   because
>   'clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls;assembly=System.Windows.Controls.Toolkit'
>   is an unknown namespace.

**Further Edits:**

All I had to do was name them. Oddly enough, giving each Expander control a name fixed the problem. Anyone know why this could be?

Comment: Have you added a reference to "windows.controls.toolkit.dll" to your project?

Comment: does the intellisense show you something when you type toolkit: ?

Comment: @Chris, Yes it is.

@Felice, Yes it does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your references seem fine, double check that the Expander class exists in the System.Windows.Controls namespace by viewing the objects in the object browser.  If it does, try removing the reference and recompiling.  You should receive an error (which is a good thing).  If you don't, there must be some other reference somewhere.  After removing all references so a compile error is thrown, readd the reference to the System.Windows.Controls.Toolkit dll.  It should be the v2.0.50727 and be available from the GAC if everything (Toolkit, SDK, Silverlight) are installed correctly.

Comment: Actually, all I had to do was name them.  Oddly enough, giving each `Expander` control a name fixed the problem.  Anyone know why this could be?  I don't like it when things just work without understanding why they worked and conversely why they previously didn't work.

Comment: Huh.  Weird.  I have no idea why giving them a name would fix the problem.

Comment: woow that is wierd. I've also added a x:Name attribute to my dataform which had the exact same problem and it runned fine.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem with the C1Expander class. Giving the control a name didn't work for me. Initially, I used the namespace

```
xmlns:c1Ext="clr-namespace:C1.Silverlight.Extended;assembly=C1.Silverlight.Extended.5"
```

Using a different namespace name

```
xmlns:ComponentOneExtensions="clr-namespace:C1.Silverlight.Extended;assembly=C1.Silverlight.Extended.5"
```

instead fixed it. Note that only the name changed an not the clr-namespace stuff. Don't know why though...

Answer (score 1):

Just Added a **x:Name"controlName"** to control from other assembly and bingo..Its working just completely fine. Can anybody explain the behavior.?

Comment: Just want to confirm that we had the same problem with our control that lived in another assembly and that by giving the control a name also solved the problem. So thanks...but would like to understand why this fixes the issue if anyone knows the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Had simlar issue with DataGrid. Adding x:Name also works for me.